# Problems with Ubuntu Server 18.04 installation

Tags: boot, networking, server, hardware

I am doing my best to troubleshoot the problem with my server. Here is the context.

- I have a dysfunctional server. It used to work. Let's say the SSD on it was formatted.
- I changed the RAM (store bought).
- I have installed Ubuntu Server 18.04 on the SSD, prepared it for SSH from my main computer, and shoved it back in the server.
- I am by no means an expert in servers. But I was until today able to every time setup SSH and use servers, be it on VMs or classic servers, although I was installing it on the machine directly, I mean by that with screen access, seeing what is displayed directly on the machine.
- I have no graphics card (not an issue, used to work without) near me atm.

Problem:

- When I turn the machine on, I expect it to appear on the router's page, with its IP, just to tell me that indeed it booted.

   Well, it doesn't appear on that page. All the other devices do.

*Any advice is welcome. Any idea on what to do, throw it in here! 

 You can also tell me to buy stuff if you think it will solve the problem...*

I tried:

- Yes, Ubuntu server was working perfectly fine on my computer.
- I restarted the server twice in the hope that the second time the BIOS wouldn't kick in (just in case)
- I tested the RAM slot for every experiment I did.
- I double-checked the cable routing.
- I checked that the ethernet cable works.
- Hoping the BIOS was the problem, I connected a keyboard and using the motherboard's installation guide, I  blindly pressed F10, went to the right with the arrow and pressed Enter to exit. I tried with a few different USB ports.
- Changed the SATA port used.

My ideas for what the problem could be:

- The RAM (although spec-wise it should work, apart from if dual rank needs special motherboards).
- BIOS problem.
- Motherboard, CPU,AM DESPERATE ! dead? (It used to work a year ago.)
- I don't know and I'm desperate!

Comment: When you say "Well, it doesn't appear on that page. All other devices do.", what do you mean by that?  Unfortunately, there is not a lot showing that it would be a OS problem.  If you can, could you add a screenshot of what you are seeing?

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/2pt753t/9
Here you go. This is what i mean.

Comment: So, this server is completely headless then?  Can you hook a monitor up to it so you can see what is going on?  Most motherboards have a built on video card that you should be able to hook up a monitor to.

Comment: sadly not. I bought a motherboard for 150€ and it didn't have a Video Port. About a year ago, when first installing, i used one of my graphics cards and put it in the server. But now, i don't have any. I could buy one, that would forever stay in there and will probably do it to have that assurance. But what then ?

Comment: It will show you if there are any problems during boot like a bad hard drive, bad RAM, etc.  Since your computer has no BMC hardware on it that allows monitoring without a monitor, you will need to get something on there so you can see to help narrow down what your issue is.